# Can i use this to play hearthstone on my acer chromebook c720

Tags: chromebook

I have an Acer chromebook c720 can I use this to play hearthstone on it? If so how do i go about that what should i install?

Comment: What do you mean about "this"? do you mean "this" is your laptop/PC? if you want to install hearthstone on ubuntu, you need to install it on Wine. follow [Install Hearthstone – Heroes of Warcraft in Ubuntu using Wine](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/04/install-hearthstone-heroes-warcraft-ubuntu-wine/) to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Install Wine or PlayOnLinux. But be wary that although it may indeed work, the performance might not be top notch.